# Calling std::function destructor while still executing it

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to dynamically change the behaviour of a method of a class, so I implemented these method calling the *operator()* of a *std::function* holding a copy of one lambda function, that depends on some values known only after the class construction, at a time.
The lambdas change the state of the class, so they reset a container holding the behaviours of all dynamic methods.
Executing the above idea I was not able to access the capture list of the lamba after resetting the container.
The following snippet reproduces the problem:

```
std::vector< std::function<void(std::string)> > vector;

int main() {

   //Change class state when variable value will be known
   std::string variableValue = "hello";

   auto function = [variableValue](std::string arg) {
     std::cout <<"From capture list, before: "<< variableValue << std::endl;
     std::cout <<"From arg,          before: " << arg << std::endl;

     vector.clear();

     std::cout << "From capture list, after: " << variableValue << std::endl;
     std::cout << "From arg,          after: " << arg << std::endl;
   };

   vector.push_back(function);

   //Dynamic method execution
   vector[0](variableValue);

   return 0;
}
```

Producing output:

```
From capture list, before: hello
From arg,          before: hello
From capture list, after:
From arg,          after: hello
```

where *variableValue* is invalidated after *vector* was clean.

Is the capture list invalidation an expected result? 
Is safe using any other local variable, not only in the capture list, after calling *std::function* destructor?
Is there a suggested way / pattern to accomplish the same behaviour in a safer way (excluding huge switches/if on class states)?

Comment: `Is the capture list invalidation an expected result?` Since the captures are stored in members of the class, yes.

Comment: What about  "the code itself"? Is the code of a std::function in some way "destroyed" when its destructor is called? Or the code can run without problem, as long as it doesn't access the memory of the class (aka members stored as a result of the capture list) ?

Comment: The code itself is in the `text` section of your binary, it's not dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 3):

We can get rid of the `std::function`, lambda and vector for this question. Since lambdas are just syntactic sugar for classes with a function-call operator, your testcase is effectively the same as this:

```
struct Foo
{
   std::string variableValue = "hello";

   void bar(std::string arg)
   {
      std::cout <<"From capture list, before: "<< variableValue << std::endl;
      std::cout <<"From arg,          before: " << arg << std::endl;

      delete this;  // ugrh

      std::cout << "From capture list, after: " << variableValue << std::endl;
      std::cout << "From arg,          after: " << arg << std::endl;
   }
};


int main()
{
    Foo* ptr = new Foo();
    ptr->bar(variableValue);
}
```

The function argument is fine because it's a copy, but after `delete this` the member `Foo::variableValue` no longer exists, so your program has undefined behaviour from trying to use it.

Common wisdom is that [continuing to run the function itself is legal](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this) (because function definitions aren't objects and cannot be "deleted"; they are just a fundamental property of your program), as long as you leave the encapsulating class's members well enough alone.

I would, however, advise avoiding this pattern unless you really need it. It'll be easy to confuse people as to the ownership responsibilities of your class (even when "your class" is autonomously-generated from a lambda expression!).

---

> Is the capture list invalidation an expected result?

Yes.

> Is safe using any other local variable, not only in the capture list, after calling std::function destructor?

Yes.

> Is there a suggested way / pattern to accomplish the same behaviour in a safer way (excluding huge switches/if on class states)?

That's impossible to say for sure without understanding what it is that you're trying to do. But you could try playing around with storing `shared_ptr`s in your vector instead… Just be careful not to capture a `shared_ptr` in the lambda itself, or it'll *never* be cleaned up! Capturing a `weak_ptr` instead can be good for this; it can be "converted" to a `shared_ptr` inside the lambda body, which will protect the lambda's life for the duration of said body.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable answer. I appreciate the hint on the shared_ptr too.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::function`'s destructor destroys the object's *target* if the object is non-empty](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), where [the *target* is the wrapped callable object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

In your case, the target is a lambda expression. When you use a lambda expression, the compiler generates a ["non-union non-aggregate class type" that contains the captures-by-value as data members and has `operator()` as a member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

When you execute `vector.clear()`, the destructors of its elements are run, and therefore the destructors of the closure's captures-by-value, which are member variables, are run.

As for captures-by-reference, ["the reference variable's lifetime ends when the lifetime of the closure object ends."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

So, it is not safe to access any capture, whether by value and by reference, after `std::function`'s destructor runs.

What about the actual `operator()`? ["Functions are not objects,"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/functions) so they don't have [lifetimes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime). So, the mere execution of the `operator()` after the destructor has been run should be fine, as long as you don't access any captures. See [the conditions under which one can safely `delete this`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this).

Comment: It's the same thing as asking whether you can safely & legally `delete *this` inside a member function as long as you don't reference any members afterwards (though of course `delete *this` is extremely evil anyway!) - the general consensus is "yes" but a citation to this effect would complete your answer.

Comment: [Reference without standard citation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7039749/560648)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks, I added a link to the C++ FAQ entry that your link links to.